# Check if application is installed on MAC OS X?

Tags: c++, macos

How can I check if an application is installed on Mac OS X? I'm trying to check this in C++

Comment: What is your definition of an application being installed? Located in `/Applications`?

Comment: run `which theapp` and check if the output is the name of the app or "no theapp in ..."

Comment: Or even, just try spawning a process with the application... If that succeeds, we can expect it's installed. If it fails, then it's not!

Comment: @MatsPetersson, `which TextEdit` shows nothing.  We're talking about applications here, not command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999) function [LSFindApplicationForInfo()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).